# ng-select add new option with async search

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I use the `[@ng-select/ng-select][1]` component many places in my software. It works well, it searches by a backend method as the user types and shows the results for selection.

Now I would like to let the user to create new items that are not on the list. How can I do this with an async list? `productNames` is an `Observable`.

```
<ng-select [name]="'productname'+index$" [items]="productNames | async"
        [attr.id]="'productname'+index$" 
        [(ngModel)]="detail.productNameNew" 
        [typeahead]="productNameInput" 
        (change)="productNameChanged($event, detail)"
        (keydown)="productNameKeyPress($event, detail)"
        [disabled]="currentSuggestion.acceptUser === null ? null : true"
        [clearable]="false">
    <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
        {{item.productName}}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
        <div class="noproduct-item">
                <div class="noproduct-head">
                    <div class="productname">{{item.productName}}</div>
                    <div class="description">{{item.description}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="noproduct-details">
                <div class="headid">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-send'></span>
                    {{item.suggestionHeadId}}
                </div>
                <div class="createduser">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>
                    {{item.createUser?.name}}
                </div>
                <div class="createddate">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>
                    {{item.createDate | date: 'yyyy.MM.dd.'}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second observable to capture the user added products and then use combineLatest to merge them.  Subscribing to the combined list will produce a new list that you can use in the ng-select.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-combinelatest